# how to find the master page from MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

i am unable to edit the master page in SharePoint designer. i guess these master page are bind with the content page latter during the page load.

is there any way to find out the master page so that it can be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open your site in SharePoint Designer. Then go to 'Master pages' (from left pane).
You'll be able to see and edit the master page, assuming you have the required permissions.

You might want to back up the file before editing or even better, make a copy, edit it and set it as the default master page.

Hope this helps.